Multiple items were found by alias 'User Type' when clicking on items in the content tree in content editor
The environment is Sitecore 10.2 on a Standalone environment. This is something I have never run into before.  I get the Multiple items were found by alias 'User Type' when I click on certain nodes of the site in the Content Editor navigation tree.
Nothing has really changed in this environment. One day it was perfectly fine, and the next day I started getting the error when clicking on a bunch of items in the content tree.
When I click on the details of the error this is what is shown.
[InvalidOperationException: Multiple items were found by alias 'User Type']
   Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Repository.ItemDefinitionRepositoryBase`1.GetItemIdByAlias(String alias) +399
   Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.Repository.ItemDefinitionRepositoryBase`1.GetByAlias(String alias, CultureInfo cultureInfo, Boolean includeInactiveVersion) +166
   Sitecore.Marketing.Definitions.DefinitionManagerBase`2.GetByAlias(String alias, CultureInfo cultureInfo, Boolean includeInactiveVersion) +216
   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DefinitionCollection`1.get_Item(String name) +156
   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContentProfile.Parse(XElement node, IMarketingDefinitions marketingDefinitions) +137
   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.<InitializeProfiles>b__56_0() +371
   System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() +734
   System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() +189
   Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.get_Profiles() +15
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditorHeader.ProfileCardsControl.RenderProfileCardIcons(Item item, HtmlTextWriter output, Boolean& hasCardsConfigured) +134
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditorHeader.ProfileCardsControl.RenderProfileCards(Item item, HtmlTextWriter output) +562
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Pipelines.RenderContentEditorHeader.ProfileCardsControl.OnInit(EventArgs e) +296
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +454
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +219
   System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) +239
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.AddControl(Control parent, Control control, String placeholder) +242
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Editor.RenderPartially(Item item, Hashtable fieldInfo, Control editorsContainer) +1447
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateEditor(Item folder, Item root, Boolean showEditor) +480
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update() +550
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(EventArgs e) +192

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +132
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +143
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7479


This was caused by a bad Sidekick migration.  A duplicate User Type Profile was imported into the Marketing Control Panel.
